# How to return raw JSON directly from a mongodb query in Java?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envinfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map getEnvInfo()
{
    BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery("{_id:'51a29f6413dc992c24e0283e'}", "{'envinfo':1, '_id': false }");
    Map envinfo= mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, Map.class, "jvmInfo");
    return envinfo;
}
```

As you can notice, the code:

1. Retrieves JSON from MongoDB
2. Converts it to a `Map` object
3. The `Map` object is then converted to JSON by Spring MongoData before it is returned to the browser.

Is it possible to directly return the raw json from MongoDb without going through the intermediate conversion steps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's two way's you can do this right now:

#### 1. Using the `CollectionCallback` on `MongoTemplate`

You can use a `CollectionCallback` to deal with the returned `DBObject` directly and simply `toString()` it:

```
template.execute("jvmInfo", new CollectionCallback<String>() {
  String doInCollection(DBCollection collection) {
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query)
    return cursor.next().toString()
  }
}
```

Yo'll still get the exception translation into Spring's `DataAccessExceptions`. Note, that this is slightly brittle as we expect only a single result to be returned for the query but that's probably something you have to take care of when trying to produce a `String` anyway.

#### 2. Register a `Converter` from `DBObject` to `String`

You can implement a Spring `Converter` to do the `toString()` for you.

```
class DBObjectToStringConverter implements Converter<DBObject, String> {
  public String convert(DBObject source) {
    return source == null ? null : source.toString();
  }
}
```

You can then either use the XML configuration or override `customConversions()` to return a `new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new DBObjectToStringConverter()))` to get it registered with your `MongoConverter`. You can then simply do the following:

```
String result = mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, String.class, "jvmInfo");
```

I will add the just showed converter to Spring Data MongoDB and register it by default for the upcoming 1.3 GA release and port the fix back to 1.2.x as part of the fix for [DATAMONGO-743](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-743).

Comment: I have a question! Can I do the same but using MongoRepository?

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the following error message.
"readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT"

Answer (score 9):

As Oliver points out, you can use Spring Data for that, but an alternative which you may or may not prefer would be to use MongoDB's more low-level Java Driver. Take a look at the [MongoDB Java Driver 3.x](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) or [MongoDB Java Driver 2.x](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver) documentation for instructions on using that driver.

Basically, what you need to do is this:

## MongoDB Java Driver 3.x

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");    
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "51a29f6413dc992c24e0283e");

try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator()) {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
}
```

## MongoDB Java Driver 2.x

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");    
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "51a29f6413dc992c24e0283e");

try (DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query)) {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
}
```

That will print out all the documents in the collection that have a field `_id` with a value `51a29f6413dc992c24e0283e`.

Comment: Someone downvoted this? Would be interested to know what's wrong with it. I didn't test it, but it's practically copy-pasted from the docs.

Comment: There's three aspects: first, it's not that you can't do it with Spring Data. I'm just about to prepare an answer to see how it works. Second, your is dumping stuff to standard out, not returning a `String`. Third, you're code is not handling any exceptions or the like. I am aware that this is sample code, but you get all of this out of the box *if* you use Spring Data, so using your code in a scenario where everything else is implemented with Spring Data would result in inconsistent behavior.

Comment: If you can do it with spring data, it would be interesting to see how you do it with that. As for returning a string, and not handling exceptions, those are pretty trivial. Any programmer worth their salt can figure out how to return the result of `cursor.next()` instead of system outting it.

Comment: Gotcha. In general there's nothing wrong with code you showed. It's just that people expect to get certain behavior when working with SD MongoDB (exception translation etc.) which they don't get with your sample. And as the original poster seems to be using SD MongoDB for his code and was explicitly asking for it I think "You should use something else" is not a great way to deal with it. It's like someone asking for an Android app and you tell him "Get an iPhone" :). No offense! I've just posted my answer: in short - it'll work OOTB in a bit but can be achieved easily right now already.

Answer (score -3):

For me the following worked perfectly:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.bson.Document;

List<Document> documents = mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class, "collection_name");
```

Comment: Isn't the question asking for rawJson? you returned a list of object here

Comment: If by rawJson he means the 'raw' json fields, then Document should do the job.